# Avoid takeover of guest user when session expires in LWR community

Tags: session, guest-user, lwr

According to this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389610&type=1), the guest user of an LWR community is taking over once a session is expired. We're having major problems with this as we've created custom user settings where a user is able to change his user information. Unfortunately it happened that a customers user session expired and changed the guest user's information such as name and email.

We implemented multiple things trying to avoid this:

- Check the isGuest property in the LWC component and only allow changes if this property is false (seems to be false even tho the guest user profile took over the session)
- Check if the current's user name is not the name of the guest user
- Applied validation rule in the user object to block changes for this specific user
- The guest user profile doesn't have any permissions on the user object

Unfortunately none of this was avoiding the change of the guest user.

Is there a way to not let the guest user profile take over the session and directly forward to the login page as soon as the session expires?

Many thanks and best regards